# Laravel 5.5, how to create a validation rule for case sensitive?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I want to validate a array where it should include case sensitive.
Ex, If One value is 'Small' and another value 'small', it should say Same values are not allowed. I tried distinct, it accepts even if it in lowercase. Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, well there are two ways, first convert values before validation, second use distinct with ignore case `distinct:ignore_case`

Comment: you can use this condition "regex:/[A-Za-z1-9 ]/"